# Errors from softlayer slcli dns commands

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to manage my Softlayer forward zones but am hitting repeated error 500s coming from Softlayer. I am using the python API, but it may be easier to show you the results from slcli itself, as that is failing with what looks like the same reason. Presumably this eliminates user-error from the list of causes, and instead suggests there's a problem in Softlayer itself.

> ben$ slcli --version

```
slcli (SoftLayer Command-line), version 5.2.0
```

*EXAMPLE WHERE THE CLI WORKS*

> ben$ slcli dns record-list 1975129

```
:..........:................................:.......:.......:.............................................:
:    id    :                         record :  type : ttl   : data                                        :
:..........:................................:.......:.......:.............................................:
: 66566069 :                              @ :  SOA  : 86400 : ns1.softlayer.com.                          :
: 66566070 :                              @ :   NS  : 86400 : ns1.softlayer.com.                          :
: 66566071 :                              @ :   NS  : 86400 : ns2.softlayer.com.                          :
: 67415149 :                     <REDACTED> : CNAME : 86400 : <REDACTED>                                  :
: 67415146 :                     <REDACTED> : CNAME : 86400 : <REDACTED>                                  :
: 67415205 :                     <REDACTED> : CNAME : 86400 : <REDACTED>                                  :
: 67415008 :                     <REDACTED> : CNAME : 86400 : <REDACTED>                                  :
: 67415204 :                     <REDACTED> : CNAME : 86400 : <REDACTED>                                  :
: 67415151 :                     <REDACTED> : CNAME : 86400 : <REDACTED>                                  :
: 67415148 :                     <REDACTED> : CNAME : 86400 : <REDACTED>                                  :
: 67415207 :                     <REDACTED> : CNAME : 86400 : <REDACTED>                                  :
: 67415150 :                     <REDACTED> : CNAME : 86400 : <REDACTED>                                  :
: 67415147 :                     <REDACTED> : CNAME : 86400 : <REDACTED>                                  :
: 67415206 :                     <REDACTED> : CNAME : 86400 : <REDACTED>                                  :
:..........:................................:.......:.......:.............................................:
```

[Yes, I have redacted data which I don't want to share]

*EXAMPLE WHERE THE CLI DOES NOT WORK*

> slcli dns record-list 1636743

```
SoftLayerAPIError(SOAP-ENV:Server): Internal Error
```

I suspect Softlayer can't handle the number of records we have created in forward zone 1636743. Can you confirm this, and provide guidance on how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re right about the error being thrown because of the amount of records.
But slcli can handle this using the next workaround:

```
slcli call-api Dns_Domain getResourceRecords --id=1636743 --limit=5
```

For further information on how to use call-api command you could review this link:

https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python/blob/master/SoftLayer/CLI/call_api.py

Comment: Thanks - very helpful. Presumably there's no direct equivalent for the SoftLayer.dns manager? It doesn't look like it from the docs. In this case, what do you recommend the best approach is?

Comment: The best approach would be to use "call-api" for complex requests such as the one provided as example, furthermore, using it you can use any service, method, object mask, object filter or result limit in your request. The link I've sent has some examples embedded in the source code.

Comment: Perfect - thanks for answering. I assumed that would be the case, but wanted to make sure this capability wasn't already embedded in any of the high level helper calls.